# Internal pressure in rigid gasoline tank from increase in temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

I was hoping to find a chart (or detailed table) that depicts the increase in internal pressure for a rigid tank full of gasoline from increases in temperature.

If this is not available then I wanted to understand if I can calculate this based on Gay-Lussac's Law or if there is something else I should be aware of? Based on Gay-Lussac's law and based on a starting pressure of 1 bar at 0 degrees celsius (273 Kelvin), I calculated that the increase in internal pressure from a 50 degrees celsius increase in temperature was approx. 17%, but this sounds very low?

Comment: Don't trust ChatGPT. It uses probabilistic modeling to present a sequence of words with (effectively) no verification that it makes a truthful statement (and in many cases, it outright lies to you).

Comment: @KyleKanos - Don't distrust it either. Try it and check the answer. It is often very helpful. I just tried these two question in ChatGPT. "what is Gay-Lussac's law?" and "If a container has a pressure of 1 bar at 0 C, what is the pressure at 50 C?". I got clear, correct answers. P = 1.18 bar.

Comment: @mmesser314 I also tried it with *bard*, and the result I got was bollocks... This was the formula it used $P2 = P1 * (1 + (T2 - T1)/273)$ irrespective of what $T1$ I gave it. At least Microsoft's Edge Chatbot refused to give me a numerical answer.

Comment: @hyportnex - It looks like Bard isn't as good as ChatGPT for physics. I got this formula from it. P = 1 bar * (50 C / 0 C). Google says that Bard doesn't look up answers. It generates them from its model. This might be a better approach for poetry than physics.

Comment: Because this thread has been closed, please ask this question again on PhysicsForums.com, and I will provide the correct answer for the case where the gasoline is treated properly as a multicomponent mixture of hydrocarbons with differing equilibrium vapor pressures at each temperature.

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to find out is how the saturated vapour pressure (SVP) of gasoline varies with temperature. It will not depend on the volume of space above the liquid [as long as, if changes are made to these, e.g. by drawing off some liquid, time is allowed for equilibrium to be reached between molecules evaporating from the liquid and molecules returning to it by random bombardment].

Using data from https://file.scirp.org/Html/70527_70527.htm#t1
and an approximate relationship based on the Clausius-Clapeyron equation we have
$$p_{\text{sat vap}}=\left[2.54\times 10^{10}\ \text{Pa}\right]\exp \left( -\tfrac L{RT}\right) $$
in which the molar latent heat of vaporisation of gasoline, $L\approx 35100\ \text{J mol}^{-1}$, $R=8.31\ \text{J mol}^{-1}\text K^{-1}$ and $T$ is the kelvin temperature.

To the SVP you will need to add the partial pressure of the air in the tank. This can be calculated using $\frac{p_1 V_1}{T_1}=\frac{p_2 V_2}{T_2}$ assuming that the tank isn't opened from when $_1$ applies to when $_2$ applies. $T$ is the kelvin temperature and $V$ is the volume of the space above the gasoline. If this space is open to the atmosphere and at a lowish temperature (say 273 K) just before it is sealed, and we'll say that just after sealing, values $_1$ apply, then we can take $p_1$ as atmospheric pressure.

Thermal expansion of the tank and the drop in liquid level due to vaporisation will tend to increase the volume $V$ of the space above the liquid if temperature increases; thermal expansion of the liquid will tend to reduce it. The resultant effect may well be small enough to ignore, that is to put $V_1=V_2$.

Comment: Isn't gasoline a multicomponent mixture of hydrocarbons of different molecular weights (and pure-vapor vapor pressures)?

Comment: @ Chet Miller I did worry about this. I did check that the data for gasoline on the website that I've cited fitted the C-C derived equation to within about 10% over a temperature range of a about 50 K.